# JMeter loop until a response value changes

Tags: jmeter

I would like to accomplish the following workflow using JMeter

- Get the results from a URL call  (Ex: http://somewhere.com/getResults)
- If the response message contains "someVar=SUCCESS" the JMeter test will pass
- else if the response message contains "someVar=FAIL" the JMeter test will fail
- else if the response message is different, wait x seconds and try the block of code again. Attempt to retry the block of code a maximum of y number of times.

Is something like this possible in JMeter?  If so, does anyone have an example?

Answer (score 7):

This tutorial should fully answer your need:

- http://www.sourcepole.ch/2011/1/4/waiting-for-a-page-change-in-jmeter

Comment: In case of link rot the supplied link details using a WHILE loop. Set a user defined variable outside the loop, use that variable in the WHILE condition, and then use a beanshell sampler to set the variable based on the response.

Answer (score 2):

The most straightforward way to go is using [JMeter Assertions](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#assertions).

The most powerful of them is [Beanshell Assertion](http://blazemeter.com/blog/queen-jmeters-built-componentshow-use-beanshell).

In regards to your use cases following code sample may help:

```
if new String(data).contains("someVar=SUCCESS")
    Failure = false;
else
    Failure = true;
```

Similarly for `FAIL`

For retrying you can use [While Controller](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#While_Controller) using some variable as condition like `continue` which is set to `true`. Retry as many times as required, when you're fine - just set `continue` variable to `false`.

Comment: Yes. And add error message to inform what and where the issue is like this: FailureMessage = "Thread: " + ctx.getThreadGroup().getName() + " someVar: " + data;

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's quite possible.

I don't have an example offhand, but here are the components you'll need.
The logic should be straight forward:

HTTP Sampler
http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request

Assertions (this will raise a user defined error)
http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#assertions

While Controller
http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#While_Controller

Regular expressions in JMeter (article)
http://community.blazemeter.com/knowledgebase/articles/65150-using-regex-regular-expression-extractor-with-jm

User Defined Vaiables (article)
http://blazemeter.com/blog/afternoon-delightuser-defined-variablesavoid-code-duplication